# Array#uniq のブロックで条件を指定した時に最初の要素が保持されるのは保証されていますか？

Tags: ruby

例えば次のような配列があり

```
a = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 3}]
```

これを以下のようにブロックを使った`uniq`メソッドで
統合した時に先頭の要素が残るのですが、

```
a.uniq{|i| i.values_at(:a)}
# => {a: 1, b: 2}
```

このように「先頭に近い要素が残る」という動作は保証されていますか？

ドキュメントを確認してみたのですが、明確な記述が見つけられませんでした。
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruby 2.3のドキュメントでは以下のように書かれています。なので「先頭に近い要素が残る」という動作は保証されています。

> self is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.
>   http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq

ただし、ruby 2.2のドキュメントでは特に記述されていないように見えました。
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq

調べてみたところ、2.3には以下のドキュメントの改善が取り込まれているようです。
プルリクエストのdescriptionによれば2.3以前でもtest_array.rbに「先頭に近い要素が残る」動作のテストがあるようです。

> It's not guaranteed in the docs that for the method works like this:
>        [1,2,3,4,5].uniq {|x| x.odd? }  #=> [1, 2]
>   but there is a test for it in test_array.rb and jruby seems to also visit array elements in order.
>   https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/845

お使いのRubyのドキュメントに「先頭に近い要素が残る」動作についての記述がない場合は、「先頭に近い要素が残る」動作のテストがあるかどうか確認してみてはいかがでしょうか。